# Cause of gated clock

Tags: hardware, vhdl

I have this code in VHDL. When I try to compile it - it says "Gated clock net clock_en is sourced by a combinatorial pin." Has anyone an idea how to get rid of this warning?
I have searched all over the internet and cant find the solution. It seems that gated clock is sometimes even useful, but when designing HW it is a warning.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;

entity ledc8x8 is
port(
    SMCLK: in std_logic;
    RESET: in std_logic;
    ROW: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    LED: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
);
end ledc8x8;

architecture behavioral of ledc8x8 is
signal count: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');          -- hlavni citac
signal row_count: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10000000";       -- prepinac radku
signal clock_en: std_logic;                         -- CE
signal output_logic: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);      -- "vystup"
begin

process(count, SMCLK, RESET, clock_en)
begin
    if RESET = '1' then
        count <= (others => '0');
    elsif SMCLK = '1' and SMCLK'event then
        count <= count + 1;
    end if;
    if count="11111110" then
        clock_en <= '1'; else
            clock_en <= '0';
    end if ;
end process;

process(clock_en, RESET)
begin   
   if RESET = '1' then
        row_count <= "10000000";
    elsif clock_en = '1' and clock_en'event then
        row_count <= row_count(0) & row_count(7 downto 1);
    end if;
end process;


process(row_count)
begin
    case row_count is                      
        when "00000001" => output_logic <= "11110110";
        -- more switch options
    end case;                               
end process;


    ROW <= row_count; 
    LED <= output_logic;


end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

As you discovered in your answer, you were using a clock *enable* as a clock. I would recommend that you write it this way, though:

```
process(RESET, SMCLK)
begin   
  if RESET = '1' then
    row_count <= "10000000";
  elsif SMCLK = '1' and SMCLK'event then
    if clock_en = '1' then
      row_count <= row_count(0) & row_count(7 downto 1);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

It may work the other way (maybe), but it's not conventional to put the enable check on the same line as the rising edge check. Note also that this means you don't need `clock_en` in your sensitivity list.

Your other clocked process should be rewritten as well. Assuming you want the assignment to `clock_en` to be combinational, you should really put it in a separate process:

```
process(RESET, SMCLK)
begin
  if RESET = '1' then
    count <= (others => '0');
  elsif SMCLK = '1' and SMCLK'event then
    count <= count + 1;
  end if;
end process;

process (count)
begin
  if count="11111110" then
    clock_en <= '1';
  else
    clock_en <= '0';
  end if ;
end process;
```

You could also write the second process here as a one-line concurrent statement:

```
clock_en <= '1' when count = "11111110" else '0';
```

Combining independent clocked and unclocked code in the same process is not a recommended coding style for various reasons.

Comment: Thanks for help. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The line with clock_en'event - asking for rising edge did the problem. Replaced to ask for rising edge of SMCLK signal.

```
process(RESET, SMCLK)
begin   
   if RESET = '1' then
        row_count <= "10000000";
    elsif clock_en = '1' and SMCLK = '1' and SMCLK'event then         
        row_count <= row_count(0) & row_count(7 downto 1);
      end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: This is not the best way to write this code, and your code has several other significant problems.

Comment: Synchronous processes should only have their clock and an asynchronous reset (if used) in the sensitivity list. Synchronous resets and other control signals (like `clock_en` here) should not trigger a process. You don't even need the `clock_en` signal in this case. Just merge the process updating `row_count` into the first process.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix your code, but isn't it somewhat bad form to unaccept another user's answer and accept your own 4 months after the fact?

Comment: @ fru1tbat Oh yeah, was revising the answers and haven't noticed that theres one above. Thanks for pointing out.